# get return value from restful web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

I am calling a restful web service like this:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    url: 'http://myserver/Register/Register.svc/json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{"ContactObject":{"Organisation":"Wasps and Ants Ltd.","FirstName":"Arthur"}}',
    error: function (request, status, error) { alert(error) },
    success: function ()
    {
    //process return data
    alert('hello');
    }
});
```

When posting to the web service, a method is called which writes the data passed to it to a database and returns a Boolean to indicate success or failure.

In the code above, the alert('hello') is being displayed and data is being written to the database. How do I access the Boolean that is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,   Add `function (result)`

```
success: function (result)
{
   //process return data
   alert('hello'+result);
}
```

Comment: if I do as you suggest the alert contains:

hello [object Object]

how do I find what's in the object?

Comment: can you post your ajax json response, or `result.yourobjectname`

Comment: When you say 'result.yourobjectname' do you mean the object (method) I am calling in the web service?

Comment: Since you have used `json` method, you response like ` {['message'=>'success']}`, in that case you need to use `result.message`

Comment: In the code I am trying to get to work it says: The response to the POST request is the JSON formatted result of method JSONDataPost(Person PersonObject).



1
 
{"JSONDataResult":true}
 
I have tried result.JSONDataResult but it says undefined

Comment: `http://jsonlint.com/` online json validator. copy and paste your json response. once it is valid then you can call like `result.JSONDataResult`

Comment: Sorry, how do I copy and paste the json response?

Comment: firefox, firebug or devloper tools `net` panel, you can find the ajax response

Comment: I'm using IE - it's a corporate intranet, IE only. I have Developer Tools open in a window next to my browser window. Each time I submit the page, it just shows the source of the page. I can't access any values of anything?

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Comment: C# - both for the restful web service and for the calling application.

Comment: Because am not familiar in C#. Last silver bullet, remove `dataType: 'json',` and simply alert the `alert('hello'+result);` in success

Comment: still says hello [object Object'

Comment: You juts return response as html from your service.

Comment: I just called it from code behind in C# - the return value looks like this "{\"JSONDataPostResult\":true}"

Comment: the reason is considered as whole thing as string, thats is the issue now, meanwhile, it is not valid json even, can you construct valid josn return response

Comment: To be honest, I can't see how the return is being constructed. There is an OperationContract that calls bool JSONDataPost(Contact, ContactObject) and the method JSONDataPost takes the data from the object passed in and saves it to the database. If successful it returns a bool - true. The ResponseFormat of the OperationContract is set to WebMessageFormat.Json and this takes 'true' and returns what I wrote above. I'm thinking I'll give up and return xml.